# String Cloud Stream httpclient processor expected-response-type as JSON

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using httpclient processor as one of my steps, as follows (specified in Shell syntax as I'm testing locally, newlines added for readability here):

```
dataflow:>stream create --name test <sourceConfig> | 
  httpclient --httpclient.urlExpression='''https://host/restUrl''' 
    --httpclient.body-expression=null 
    --headers-expression=\"{Accept: 'application/json', <otherHeaders>}\" 
  | log" --deploy
```

The service returns a Map with a single entry, with a list as a value.

```
{ "key" : [ { "name" : "theName", ... }, ... ] }
```

By default, the REST call response body is interpreted as a String. I'd like to specify a `--httpclient.expected-response-type` option to have the body parsed into JSON. Per the [docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/processor/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-httpclient), I need to specify a `java.lang.Class<?>` for this, and I'm not sure what class to specify, even after much digging in docs, unit tests, and POMs. Does anyone know?

Or, do I need to perform the conversion manually in the `--reply-expression`? Either way, I think I still need to know which JSON library Spring Cloud Stream is using, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like you are missing something here in the knowledge. 
The JSON is a string repesentation of data in some specific format.

That is already up to your service to convert that string to the target class. The same JSON different service may parse to different domain object. I can convert it into class `Foo`, you - to `Bar`. That is how that `expected-response-type` is provided to be protocol free and let you to decide to what to convert that JSON.

The Jackson processor is used for converting to/from JSON. But again: the target POJO is your own class.

You can convert JSON string to the `java.util.Map` though, but it isn't better than just string representation of JSON.

More over it is a `processor` and it sends its result to the next step in the microservices chain, over the network. When you convert that JSON to POJO, it will converted to the JSON back on the binder's producer side. Does it make sense to convert it here for nothing?

There is also `JsonPropertyAccessor` for SpEL which let you to get access to the field in the target JSON without converting it into the POJO.

So, consider do not worry about JSON conversion and just receive it from the REST service and send it out as is - in string repesentation!

Comment: Absolutely possible I'm misunderstanding. Given the String in JSON format from the question, how would I have httpclient reply with just a list of `name`s? I thought I'd need JSON in order to accomplish that with SpEL.

Comment: Well, you need `jsonPath` for that purpose: http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_advanced_spel_expressions. And indeed it is in the classpath anyway

Comment: `httpclient.reply-expression=#jsonPath(body,'''$.key[*].name''')`: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Thanks, the jsonPath part is what I missed. [Docs for splitter](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/splitter/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-splitter/README.adoc) mention use of jsonPath, but httpclient doesn't, so I didn't realize it was available for that processor.

Comment: I ended up using `--httpclient.reply-expression\"#jsonPath(body,'$.key[*].name')\"`. When I tried Artem's suggestion, I got a stacktrace from jsonpath `Missing property in path $[''$']`. I knew that was the correct jsonPath expression though because it worked in the [JsonPath evaluator](http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/) with a sample of my actual data. I figured it had to be a shell quoting issue and it was.

Comment: Correct, that is shell issue. I don't work with SCDF, so I don't remember that proper escaping